# C++ no operator "<<" match these operand (inheritance)

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, runtime-error

I have just recently started class inheritance in c++. While I was making a "Test" program, a error occurred with the cout statement. No clue how to fix it and would be appreciate your response.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Power{
public:
    void isWeak(){
        cout << " Weak"<< endl;
    }
    void isStrong(){
        cout << " Strong" << endl;
    }
};

class Person:public Power{};

class Person2:public Power{};

int main(){
    Person human;
    Person2 human2;

    cout << "Human is " << human.isWeak() << endl; //error
    cout << "Human 2 is " << human2.isStrong() << endl; //error
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

the main()'s cout statement has that error between the output and human

Comment: You're using a `void` expression as though it has a value

Comment: Thanks Y'all for your splendid answer. Most of your answer did help me learn more about the program and my mistake so thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change the functions to

```
char const *isWeak(){
    return " Weak";
}
char const *isStrong(){
    return " Strong";
}
```

As currently defined, both functions have `void` return type, which means the `cout` statements within main are trying to print `void`, which doesn't make sense, and is the cause of the error.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to print a `void`:

```
cout << "Human is " << human.isWeak() << endl;
```

is the same as typing

```
cout << "Human is " << void << endl;
```

Which will not compile.  What you need to do is define your functions in either of the following ways:

```
class Power
{
public:
    std::string isWeak()
    {
        return std::string(" is weak");
    }

    std::string isStrong()
    {
        return std::string(" is strong");
    }
};
```

Or, change your code:

```
cout << "Human is ";
human.isWeak();
cout << endl;
cout << "Human 2 is ";
human2.isStrong();
cout << endl;
```

Comment: There's no need to write `std::string(" is weak")` and so on. You can return the literal directly and it'll automatically be used to construct the `std::string`.

Comment: @BrianBi True.  I placed it there for clarity.  The resulting assembly is identical.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to 'print' a 'void' statement in `cout << "Human is " << human.isWeak() << endl;`

You'll need to change your `isWeak` and `isStrong` functions to return a `std::string`/`const char*` or change the way you call them:

to string:

```
const char* isWeak() {
    return " Weak";
}
// then you can do 
cout << "Human is " << human.isWeak() << endl;
```

Or change the way you call the function:

```
cout << "Human is ";
human.isWeak();
```

Your `isWeak` and `isStrong` functions are `void` they do not return anything; calling `cout << human.isWeak()` is expecting `isWeak` to return something (an int, string, double, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with isWeak() and isStrong() return type. these two functions return void and you are trying to print it. you can try this-

```
cout << "Human is " ;
human.isWeak();
cout << endl;

 cout << "Human 2 is " ;
 human2.isStrong();
cout << endl;
```